# Unexpected internal Active Directory error when calling New-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Something strange happens to me. I have created a simple code to create users in Active Directory in PowerShell using the splatting structure. A few days ago everything was going wonderfully until I found out that today my script is not working.

I have reviewed:

- Connectivity with the server through AD ports 389 and 636.
- `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName XXXX.com -Port 389`
- Checked if with my user I can obtain information from a user with

These tests are satisfactory, but the error is repeated when creating a user with this script.

I think the error is not in the code but in the creation permissions.

Can anyone shed some light?

Always wrong. I will add the script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$parametros = @{
    SamAccountName  = ""
    GivenName       = ""
    Surname         = ""
    UserPrincipalName = ""
    Name            = ""
    DisplayName     = ""
    Description     = ""
    AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Contraseña123" -Force)
    Enabled         = $false
}

$parametros.SamAccountName = Read-Host "Ingrese el nombre de usuario (SamAccountName)"
$parametros.GivenName = Read-Host "Ingrese el nombre del usuario"
$parametros.Surname = Read-Host "Ingrese los apellidos del usuario"
$parametros.UserPrincipalName = Read-Host "Ingrese el UserPrincipalName"
$parametros.Name = Read-Host "Ingrese el usuario"
$parametros.DisplayName = "$($parametros.Surname), $($parametros.GivenName)"
$parametros.Description = Read-Host "Ingrese el nombre seguido de los apellidos"

# Llamar al cmdlet New-ADUser con splatting
New-ADUser @parametros
```

User permissions:

- launch script with multiple users
- administrator permission

When executing the code this is the error:

```
# Llamar al cmdlet New-ADUser con splatting
New-ADUser @parametros
Ingrese el nombre de usuario (SamAccountName): test36
Ingrese el nombre del usuario: Test
Ingrese los apellidos del usuario: SurName1 Surname2
Ingrese el UserPrincipalName: test36
Ingrese el usuario: test36
Ingrese el nombre seguido de los apellidos: test36 SurName1 Surname2
New-ADUser : Error interno
En línea: 23 Carácter: 1
+ New-ADUser @parametros
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=test36,CN=Users,DC=XXXX,DC=com:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1359,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
 

PS C:\Users\XXXX>
```

The error received in the event viewer is as follows:
EVENT: 4100

> Id. de error completo =
> ActiveDirectoryServer:1359,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
>
> Contexto:
> Gravedad = Warning
> Nombre de host = Windows PowerShell ISE Host
> Versión de host = 5.1.17763.5122
> Id. de host = 4dec9f2a-a5b6-4331-843a-6684f3495bd6
> Aplicación host = C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe
> Versión del motor = 5.1.17763.5122
> Id. de espacio de ejecución = 9d8fb293-35e9-45e4-a229-a0359d4bfde0
> Id. de canalización = 12
> Nombre de comando = New-ADUser
> Tipo de comando = Cmdlet
> Nombre de script =
> Ruta de acceso de comando =
> Número de secuencia = 20
> Usuario = DOMAIN\USER
> Usuario conectado =
> Id. de shell = Microsoft.PowerShell
>
> Datos de usuario:

Comment: No problem :) That error id usually indicates that the DSA refused the operation because of some conflict between the schema (or DC security policy), or because of some failure in verifying that - I'd start by checking the System event log channel on the DC you're talking to :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen update!

Comment: That's just PowerShell logging the same error to the event log. You'll want to inspect the System event log channel _on the domain controller_

Comment: The active directory may not exist.  The real error may be a credential issue connecting to the server.  Does user exist (DOMAIN\USER Usuario)?  I would try using a File Explorer over the network and see if you can access the user folder from same remote machine.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find the domain controller for the channel...
Could you tell me how to search for it? @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Check `$env:LOGONSERVER` (or `nltest /DSGETDC:$env:USERDNSDOMAIN`)

Comment: @jdweng With my user I can launch a script to see attributes of other users. But don't create them

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessenwith: nltest /DSGETDC:$env:USERDNSDOMAIN

I can verify that the domain is correct, but the forest name shows DOMAIN-XXX
Is it possible that having a different domain name and forest name will cause me an error?

Comment: Forest and Domain isn't necessarily the same. The line in the output you want is the one that starts with "DC:" - you'll want to inspect the logs on _that_ machine. Is there not a local AD admin you can consult on these things?

Comment: No, I am the sysadmin on a domain inherited from other technicians. Now I see myself resolving conflictive issues@MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Did you try File Explorer?  Try creating a new file with File Explorer.  The File Explorer will make it easy to find the root cause of issue.

Comment: I can create files in file explorer. I can even give my user full permissions to modify an OU in which I launch the script. @jdweng

Comment: In addition to Mathias' helpful tips: Assuming that `1359` is the error number, there's not much info out there, but perhaps this helps: https://serverfault.com/a/1101426/176094 May be worth asking on [SF] in general.

Comment: Then all the permission are correct.   File Explorer will use the user login credentials.   You want PS to also use the login credentials.  So in PS use $c = Get-Credential

Comment: In the post you recommend me, there is a resolution annotation in which they recommend to disable AllowNT4Crypto. Do you recommend it? @mklement0

Comment: I have no expertise in this area, but perhaps @MathiasR.Jessen can weigh in. Also note the other answer there, which uses a different solution.

Comment: Disabling AllowNT4Crypto should be fine as long as you don't have legacy (pre-Vista/2008) Windows boxes as domain members. It might also impact applications that employ older client libraries (think SAMBA clients and the likes) for auth against AD.

Comment: I've been thinking that it could be an issue of permissions, trust relationship...? It doesn't make sense that one day I could launch the script and the next week I can't. @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: CONSULTATION UPDATE.
The code mentioned above is working.
The problem was the synchronization of AD users and their databases.
Thanks greetings for all